# Creating C++ program to run shell script

Tags: c++, shell

I'm trying to write a program that takes a command line argument value and pass it to a shell script.

I already created the shell script: " findname.sh "

and this is what I have already written for my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
char * input1;
char my_command[50];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    input1=argv[1];
    char* command_line;
    sprintf(my_command, "./findname.sh %s", input1);
    if(argc != 2){
       system("findname.sh");
    cout << "usage: "<< argv[0] << " Some Value\n";
    exit(0);
}
command_line=argv[1];
cout << "You entered  :" << command_line <<" from the command line." << endl;
```

But when I try to rune findName xxxxxx
it says command not found

Comment: I think you accidentally a question.

Comment: I'd really like to call this program with a first argument's that's 36 characters long.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of helping you, you probably want to change:

```
system("findname.sh");
```

to

```
system(my_command);
```

But your code is a mess and does not compile anyway.  This is clearly not the code you ran, if it ran.

Get rid of the syntax errors, and all the unnecessary stuff, and you'll be down to three lines or so that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
system("./findname.sh");
```

instead of

```
system("findname.sh");
```

Comment: It works a lot better if you read the formatting tips. Among them, you'll find that you should not use HTML tags for formatting.

Comment: That still does not include the argument to the shell script.